# App-store link not opening for my published IOS app

Tags: ios, flutter

I have published my application on app-store and I try to get the link of my application.
I knew that I can go to section "App Information" , then "Additional Information", then click on "View on app store" but I always get this loading page without showing my app. Any idea why?
[image]

Comment: I guess you have a network issue. I can load it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Link looks not good,
Example : https://apps.apple.com/fr/app/whatsapp-messenger/id310633997

Comment: That is not correct, the shorter URL syntax, e.g. https://apps.apple.com/app/id310633997 works as well, even if it will choose the default store location

Comment: Your link does work for me, i manage to see your app if it's well the 'Dynamic HR'